# Installation problems with Fuerte and rosjava

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to install rosjava for use with fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04
I followed the installation instructions substituting fuerte for electric.
Everything seems to be working fine until I run the rosws update command.
I'm rather new to linux so I'm not sure what I should be doing to fix this.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
~/ros_workspace$ rosws update   
[rosjava_core] Installing https://code.google.com/p/rosjava (default) to /home/docsmiley/ros_workspace/rosjava_core
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'hg --version'
 errcode: 127:
/bin/sh: 1: hg: not found
[/vcstools]
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'rosjava_core' : Unable to create vcs client of type hg for /home/docsmiley/ros_workspace/rosjava_core: "Could not determine whether hg is installed 'hg --version returned 127, maybe hg is not installed'"

ERROR: Error processing 'rosjava_core' : Unable to create vcs client of type hg for /home/docsmiley/ros_workspace/rosjava_core: "Could not determine whether hg is installed 'hg --version returned 127, maybe hg is not installed'"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35624/installation-problems-with-fuerte-and-rosjava/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

get mercurial

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-07-02**:
sudo apt-get install mercurial